# Finding specifications for digital signal processors (DSPs) for given audio application

Tags: audio, dsp, processor, development-tools

I'm finding difficulties **choosing an adequate processor** solution for my application from my null experience with DSP:

- 8ch 24-bit @11025Hz I2S **TDM Input**
- **Beamforming** + ASNR
- MSS Multi-source selection
- DRC Dynamic Range Compession
- Frequency domain analysis (**Real FFT**)
- 5 seconds **STFT**
- **Peak Finding**
- **Comparison** algorithms
- Connectivity (**Bluetooth** @ Low Transfer Rate, just notifications)

[image: Application parameters]

I'm considering both a design which includes a Host MCU or just the DSP.

So far I'm looking at **SigmaDSP processors**:

- Pros: Provided I2S TDM interface, arithmetic blog for beamforming, cost
- Cons: Buggy and limmited Graphical Programming Interface (no c programming), only Radix-2 Complex FFT and 50% overlap analysis window are available, lack of documentation for sending a signal via SPI to Host Controller

I'm also considering **SHARC processors**, which I find overkill for my application (no codecs, no output, single input port, etc.):

- Pros: C programming flexibility, no need of Host Controller, provided I2S TDM interface
- Cons: Lack of experience with DSP programming, cost of processor, development kits, emulators and software

My questions are:

1. **How to determine required system sources** (memory, **clock frequency**, etc)?
2. Any guidance/recommendations/other families/brands I should look?

Hardware I'm using...
2x Mic Array: https://www.notwired.co/ProductDetail/NWAUDICS52000-NotWired-CO/605574/?ProdId=605574&
I2S TDM to USB: https://www.minidsp.com/products/usb-audio-interface/usbstreamer

Thank you so much,
Pedro

Comment: Hi Pedro, your original  title was "what to buy", and that's off-topic. However, your question is a totally different one: "What specs are relevant", and that is a very good and on-topic question, so I changed the title of your question!

Comment: However, it's not really clear what your sampling rates, algorithmic complexities etc are. From what you say , it sounds like you're dealing with audio sample rates (I2S input) and a rather benign amount of overall data(bluetooth), and don't have significant latency restriction at all (bluetooth). So, I'm not even sure I'd recommend a DSP at all – just use a bog-normale PC or raspberry pi or anything, somehow connect your I2S sensors, and write as much C on a proper operating system as you want.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thank you for the change on the title. I've added more detailed specifications on my application. Microphone Array Board uses I2S TDM format, which is not provided on most MCUs or single-board computers such as raspberry pi. Custom drivers could be developed but this is obviously not an option (high development cost). I do need a DSP.

Comment: hm, I don't know, I2S is really pretty common. But you might be right, the additional lane with channel information might not be available on just any single-board computer. I'd probably just go and get a cheap FPGA (Ice40), and design a quick TDM-to-SPI converter. Note that TDM is not really a standard! So, be very sure that your source can talk to your processor, really.

Comment: (other than that, if the TDM standard used is really just I2S where consecutive frames just mean different channels, well, use bog-normal I2S hardware, and many single-board computers do have I2S, and pick these channels apart in software)

Comment: I2S is a pretty common interface, TDM format is not. ICS-52000 was the world’s first TDM Microphone with an Array of 16 Devices on a single Bus. It was announced on 2016. Thus, no single-board or general purpose MCU implements a fully-functional library for it yet. I'm convinced of using a DSP, the only problem is my null practical experience with them. Thank you for the comments either way!

Comment: "ICS-52000 was the world’s first TDM Microphone with an Array of 16 Devices on a single Bus." errrrr I'm pretty sure that's marketing speech for "we at TDK invented our own version of I2S that carries more than 2 channels, and now we put 16 microphones on it, and because noone else came to the conclusion that 16 channels over I2S was a good idea, we can claim we're the first". Frankly, at some point where your bus state machine gets as complicated as this, you might just stop giving things names that "sound" like they're a standard ("TDM") and also, think about headers and packet buses.

Comment: anyway, to me this ICS-52000 datasheet looks like you simply need to daisy chain the WS buses, and (*shudder*) drive a single SPI line with all the microphone's outputs. In other words: you can probably generate a valid WS signal for the first mic  with your average MCU/raspberry pi's SPI MOSI pin, use the SPI clock to drive the SCK, and "OR" together all the SD pins of the microphones, and feed that to your MCU's SPI MISO pin.
The **hard** part, in any case, no matter what you do, will be getting the timing just right.

Comment: When it comes to reducing BOM, having all Microphones in a single bus without the need of codecs and with the advantage of digital vs analog makes a lot of sense. New applications on voice recognition are requiring this standard, where no more than 2 microphones (stereo) were needed before. You do need a WS signal equal to the FS (196KHz?), and a SCK equal to nchannels*32 bits*the sampling frequency. I don't think you can achieve the correct timing and data handling (DMAs?) with SPI.

Comment: DMA is a feature of your controller. And most microcontrollers with SPI have a DMA engine. Make your own impression, but as far as I read the timing diagrams from the datasheet, there's little problem with abusing a SPI MOSI to generate WS.

Comment: The rate problems *are* real, but if you generate the serial clock using a divider from your microcontroller, this should work. I'm not sure any DSPs have fundamentally different features which make this easier – but yeah, in the end, it's not that unlikely you'll end up with some costum glue logic in a CPLD or FPGA somewhere.

Comment: I agree, and from my knowledge/experience I could understand your point of view. However, there is a lot of interest on this application, and many people struggling getting TDM format to work on Raspberry Pi, Teensy and other platforms. I don't see an easy implementation and specially, I still see no reason for not using an audio DSP, for an audio application. There is people who don't see further than Arduino/Raspberry Pi. Hopefully I can get some help finding the specifications of my processor.

Comment: If you get TDM format working using SPI the community will be really grateful with you.

Comment: Why would I end up with a time consuming developing task on CPLD or FPGA platforms when there are DSPs specifically designed for this application?

Comment: yeah, I still maintain that "TDM" isn't really a standard, and that I feel very uneasy driving the same line from multiple devices. So, I doubt anyone, using an audio DSP or not, will have, at this point, an easy time interfacing to microphone arrays like the one you describe. I'm not really convinced that you save that much in PCB real estate and parts costs by daisy chaining devices like this if in the end, only a custom logic design can make things work with standard hardware...

Comment: and, if you say so, I'll believe that those DSPs will flawlessly talk to such systems. I just have my doubts until I see it. and you might roll your own logic because that might solve a lot of problems on the way, might be cheaper than using a specialized DSP, or simply is otherwise inavoidable.

Comment: Most ADI audio DSPs support TDM format within I2S interface. You can configure the the polarity, clocks, justifications, etc. ICS-52000 take care of the daisy chain, so that no extra circuitry is needed. Here you have a 2006 application note from another manufacturer: https://d3uzseaevmutz1.cloudfront.net/pubs/appNote/AN301REV1.pdf

Comment: Sorry this is actually a widely used/known standard which will be used in future devices as both processor manufacturers and microphone designers are including it.

Comment: That's actually pretty cool! My own experiments with I2S-based >2-channel audio are a few years back, and it really was a disaster back then; your best bet were basically arbitrary deep shift registers and logic to fill them with one full multi-channel frame, before handing that over to the controller logic, hence my ranting.

Answer (score 3):

There are no magic formulas.  However, for a very rough start, find the number of multiply-accumulates (MACs) you need to do per second.  That gives you a lower bound on instruction speed.

To do that, you need to first decide on some parameters:

The sample rate of each signal.

The number of signals you will apply convolutions to.

The width of each convolution in samples.

The total MACs per second is the product of all these.  Figure any competent DSP can do a MAC every cycle once it gets going on a convolution.  Of course there will be extra cycles to start and end each convolution, control overhead, communicating with elsewhere, etc.  You might, for example, start out by reserving 25% of the processor cycles to other than MACs.

Often these processors come in a family of related devices.  One strategy is to prototype with the biggest bestest, then scale down to just what you find you actually need in the production version.  The extra headroom also allows you to do what-if tests in the prototype, add code that might aid in debugging or verification, etc.  It can be very useful to have significant extra headroom in the first prototype.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer @Olin Lathrop, specially for the strategy recommendation, which shows experience in the topic. I'll probably use ADZS-SC584-EZLITE which is applicable to multiple parts as you described. I'm still concerned though about community support on a relatively new 5th generation of SHARC processors. Also, CCES Embedded Studio is not free, which will be a constrain after the 1-year license. Finally I need to check whether if a TDM compatible serial port is available in the board, since many times ports are already used for other ADC/DAC codecs.